# React call to different files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my base html script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <head><title>React.js on Repl.it</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="asdf"></div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and it calls to the app.js, how do i make it call to a different file such as otherapp.js
Bundle.js calls to app.js

Comment: Bundle.js calls to app.js

Comment: Can you add our component code? I am not exactly sure what is it that you are asking?

Comment: If `bundle.js` is invoking something, and you want it to invoke something else, then have you tried editing the code in `bundle.js` to do that?  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the HTML file is `bundle.js` which is the artifact that webpack creates.

If you use Create React App, open `index.js`. This file basically renders `App` to an element in your dom. In other words, it bootstraps your application. You can change `App` to `OtherApp` if you wish.